# How do I calculate a new coordinate of a point on a circle’s circumference?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, trigonometry

How do I calculate a new coordinate of a point on a circle’s circumference ; 
i have O(0,0), A(x,y) and i want to calculate B(x',y')
according to the following rule OA = λ OB like this 
http://i59.tinypic.com/aakmqc.png

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the picture (with some cropping) you referred to so that it is not lost. If you are not happy with that, you can of course edit your question back to its previous state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're doing a projection of a point `A` onto your circle.  Let's say the radius of the circle is `r` and the distance from the center of the circle to A is `d`.  Then you need `λ` such that `r = λ d`, or `λ = r/d`.

For the circle center at the origin, you have `d = Sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`.